# WSUS mmc keep crashing

Tags: windows, sql, update, wsus

I have WSUS that use MS SQL 2012 as database. Updates are stored locally on WSUS server, since we have limited Internet bandwidth. All update classes are synced from Microsoft, except drivers and new feature packs. Updates are synced in 3 languages. WSUS version is 10.0.17763.678. WSUS server itself is fully updated. Size of database `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.WSUSSQL\MSSQL\DATA\SUSDB.mdf` is about 10GB. When I try to display all updates in WSUS console - it hang for about 3-5 minutes and then  [crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGzsS.jpg).

```
The WSUS administration console was unable to connect to the WSUS Server via the remote API. 

Verify that the Update Services service, IIS and SQL are running on the server. If the problem persists, try restarting IIS, SQL, and the Update Services Service.

System.Net.WebException -- The operation has timed out

Source
System.Web.Services

Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DatabaseAccess.ApiRemotingCompressionProxy.GetWebResponse(WebRequest webRequest)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.ApiRemoting.ExecuteSPSearchUpdates(String updateScopeXml, String preferredCulture, Int32 publicationState)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DatabaseAccess.AdminDataAccessProxy.ExecuteSPSearchUpdates(String updateScopeXml, String preferredCulture, ExtendedPublicationState publicationState)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.Update.SearchUpdates(UpdateScope searchScope, ExtendedPublicationState publicationState, UpdateServer updateServer)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.AdminApiAccess.UpdateManager.GetUpdates(ExtendedUpdateScope filter)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.AdminApiAccess.BulkUpdatePropertiesCache.GetAndCacheUpdates(ExtendedUpdateScope updateScope, ComputerTargetScope computerTargetScope)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Pages.UpdatesListPage.GetListRows()
```

The query is too big and SQL just does not have time to process it. The timeout of WSUS console is very short and there is no way of increasing it. WSUS crashes only if I ask it to display unapproved - any updates, because this query is very big. If I ask to display Approved - Failed or Needed it complete the query successfully.

I tried to tweak IIS WsusPool advanced settings: setting private memory limit to 0 (unlimited), setting Queue Length to 25000, “Service Unavailable” Response Type to TcpLevel, Failure Interval (minutes) to 30, ‘Maximum Failures’ to 60, Regular Time Interval (minutes) to 0, Ping Enabled to False.

I tried running WSUS database reindex script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6f8cde49-5c52-4abd-9820-f1d270ddea61

I tried adding more cores to virtual machine up to 32 ones (SQL process still not using more than 15% CPU), adding more memory up to 32 GB (there is a lot of free memory). I tried moving disk C (database location) to faster storage.

I tried increasing asp timeout of WSUS by changing in \Program Files\Update Services\WebServices\ClientWebService\Web.Config `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />` to `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" executionTimeout="3600" />`

I tried making WSUS Server Cleanup Wizard from Options part of WSUS console. All checkboxes in cleanup wizard were checked. The wizard ran for about 5 hours and completed successfully. It deleted about 25000 not needed updates.

Actually WSUS mmc console not always crash. Right after cleanup wizard and after reindex script it successfully displayed the list of all updates, but after 2 successful tries it started to crash again.

How to make WSUS mmc condole always successfully display list of all updates?

Comment: What's the error when it crashes? 10GB is pretty normal for a WSUS DB and should not be any problem at all. Did the cleanup-wizard run through?

Comment: The error says: `Error: Connection Error. An error occurred trying to connect the WSUS server. This Error can Happen for a number of reasons. Check connectivity with the server. Please contact you network administrator if the problem persists. Click Reset Server Node to try to connect to the server again. Cleanup-wizard was running for about 4-5 hours and completed successfully. It sad that it removed about 25000 unnecessary updates from database.

Comment: This is what you get when you click "Copy Error to Clipboard"?

Comment: I uploaded detailed error message to question body. Also I noticed that WSUS crashes only if I ask it to display `unapproved - any` updates, because this query is very big. If I ask to display `Approved - Failed or Needed` it complete the query successfully.

Comment: Sadly, the script that fixes this problem (or, at least, fixed it for me) now costs US$60/year.  [Here's the new link](https://www.ajtek.ca/) but this is not a recommendation - IMO the script was not of commercial quality, and some of the functionality causes WSUS to misbehave.  For what it is worth, though, the index optimization option did significantly improve performance on my system.

Comment: ... if you have any professional database administrators on board, perhaps they could look into the problem for you?